# SVG not sized properly in CSS Grid

Tags: css, svg

I have a problem sizing an SVG inside a grid. I don't know much about SVG (except how to create them and export them from illustrator and that we can customize them by using attributes for color, fill, stroke etc.)

I've created a pen to make this easier to understand. I just want to align the starting point with line-1 and the ending point of the SVG  with line-2 like below

[image: expected result]

As you can see the SVG doesn't care much about the size I've set to my grid are overflows.

screenshot here:
[image: what I end-up with: the SVG overlaps the grid's height]

We could play around with padding to align things up but I don't want to make the grid adapt the the SVG size but the opposite. Clearly I don't want to end up with something like below because the SVG is too long and there's too much distance between the 3 lines.

[image: Here the grid is getting as big as the SVG but this is not want I want]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0em 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "svg-icon line-1" "svg-icon line-2" "svg-icon line-3";
  width: 10rem;
  height: 6rem;
}

.line-1 {
  grid-area: line-1;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.line-2 {
  grid-area: line-2;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.line-3 {
  grid-area: line-3;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.svg-icon {
  grid-area: svg-icon;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line-1">This is the line 1</div>
  <div class="line-2">This is the line 2</div>
  <div class="line-3">This is the line 3</div>
  <div class="svg-icon">
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5.24 41.91"><path
        d="M2.63.5A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,2.62,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.63.5h0m0-.5A2.62,2.62,0,1,0,5.25,2.62,2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,0Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
        fill="#fff"
      /><path
        d="M2.63.5A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,2.62,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.63.5h0m0-.5A2.62,2.62,0,1,0,5.25,2.62,2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,0Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
      /><path
        d="M2.63,37.17A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,39.29a2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.13-2.12h0m0-.5a2.62,2.62,0,1,0,2.62,2.62h0A2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,36.67Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
        fill="#fff"
      /><path
        d="M2.63,37.17A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,39.29a2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.13-2.12h0m0-.5a2.62,2.62,0,1,0,2.62,2.62h0A2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,36.67Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
      /><line
        x1="2.61"
        y1="4.87"
        x2="2.61"
        y2="37.14"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-miterlimit="10"
        stroke-width="2"
      />
      <circle cx="2.61" cy="2.62" r="2.12" fill="#fff" /><circle
        cx="2.62"
        cy="39.29"
        r="2.12"
        fill="#fff"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks for your help.

---

Solution

We can't set a height on a grid because the height of the grid is essentially determined by the width of the SVG element. So I guess we just have to remove the height on the grid and just play around with the width of the SVG so try to get the desired height of the whole thing.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 400px;
  grid-template-areas: "svg-icon line-1" "svg-icon line-2" "svg-icon line-3";
  grid-template-columns: 4rem;
}

.svg-icon svg {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.line-1 {
  grid-area: line-1;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
  align-self:start;
}

.line-2 {
  grid-area: line-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  align-self:center;
}

.line-3 {
  grid-area: line-3;
  font-size: 2em;
  align-self:end;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.svg-icon {
  grid-area: svg-icon;
  justify-self: center;
}



.my-block {
  border: solid red 1px;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="line-1">This is the line 1</div>
    <div class="line-2">This is the line 2</div>
    <div class="line-3">This is the line 3</div>
    <div class="svg-icon">
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5.24 41.91"><path
        d="M2.63.5A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,2.62,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.63.5h0m0-.5A2.62,2.62,0,1,0,5.25,2.62,2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,0Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
        fill="#fff"
      /><path
        d="M2.63.5A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,2.62,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.63.5h0m0-.5A2.62,2.62,0,1,0,5.25,2.62,2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,0Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
      /><path
        d="M2.63,37.17A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,39.29a2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.13-2.12h0m0-.5a2.62,2.62,0,1,0,2.62,2.62h0A2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,36.67Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
        fill="#fff"
      /><path
        d="M2.63,37.17A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,39.29a2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.13-2.12h0m0-.5a2.62,2.62,0,1,0,2.62,2.62h0A2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,36.67Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
      /><line
        x1="2.61"
        y1="4.87"
        x2="2.61"
        y2="37.14"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-miterlimit="10"
        stroke-width="2"
      />
      <circle cx="2.61" cy="2.62" r="2.12" fill="#fff" /><circle
        cx="2.62"
        cy="39.29"
        r="2.12"
        fill="#fff"
      />
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Clearly I don't want to end up with something like below because there's too much distance between the 3 lines" - it would help if you clearly said what you DO want not what you do not.

Comment: I've just added a screenshot aside of "I just want to align the starting point with line-1 and the ending point of the SVG with line-2" so you can see the difference with the last screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often times when you have css issues, you can remove something to address an issue - adding more is not always "more" here.  SO we can remove

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0em 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
```

Still big, but that is the width and height you chose.

```css
.my-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25rem auto;
  /* remove the auto to get the trees below for example */
}

.container {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "svg-icon line-1" "svg-icon line-2" "svg-icon line-3";
  grid-template-columns: 4rem auto;
}

.line-1 {
  grid-area: line-1;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.line-2 {
  grid-area: line-2;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.line-3 {
  grid-area: line-3;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.svg-icon {
  grid-area: svg-icon;
  justify-self: center;
}

.svg-icon svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-block {
  border: solid red 1px;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="line-1">This is the line 1</div>
    <div class="line-2">This is the line 2</div>
    <div class="line-3">This is the line 3</div>
    <div class="svg-icon">
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5.24 41.91"><path
        d="M2.63.5A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,2.62,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.63.5h0m0-.5A2.62,2.62,0,1,0,5.25,2.62,2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,0Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
        fill="#fff"
      /><path
        d="M2.63.5A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,2.62,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.63.5h0m0-.5A2.62,2.62,0,1,0,5.25,2.62,2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,0Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
      /><path
        d="M2.63,37.17A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,39.29a2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.13-2.12h0m0-.5a2.62,2.62,0,1,0,2.62,2.62h0A2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,36.67Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
        fill="#fff"
      /><path
        d="M2.63,37.17A2.12,2.12,0,1,1,.5,39.29a2.12,2.12,0,0,1,2.13-2.12h0m0-.5a2.62,2.62,0,1,0,2.62,2.62h0A2.62,2.62,0,0,0,2.63,36.67Z"
        transform="translate(-0.01)"
      /><line
        x1="2.61"
        y1="4.87"
        x2="2.61"
        y2="37.14"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-miterlimit="10"
        stroke-width="2"
      />
      <circle cx="2.61" cy="2.62" r="2.12" fill="#fff" /><circle
        cx="2.62"
        cy="39.29"
        r="2.12"
        fill="#fff"
      />
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>I have more happy trees than you</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you for your reply. You're right, I've made a mistake about the container width & height which is way too big, I've changed the code to get a container of  10rem x 6rem; Obviously, I can play around with the padding of the line-1 and line-3 to make them aligned to the SVG but it the reverse thing I would like to get: the SVG adapting to the grid size, hence to the lines size. I also have the restriction that I have work with a fixed-size container.

Comment: Not really 100% sure what you mean by I have work with a fixed-size container - so I added a wrapper around the container to illustrate something to base upon - and did some minor format to the `.container` on size to show how to do that.  Likely this you can build upon.

Comment: I've notice you removed : "width: 10rem; height: 6rem;" from the grid. I just need a fixed size for this grid.

Comment: If I take your example and add align-self on the 3 lines( start center end ), then it works. So if I want a 6rem height grid, I just have to play around with the SVG's width. It this the "classic"/"good" way of dealing with this kind of thing?

Comment: @Big_Boulard the `grid` display can be utilized either way for the size (contents determine size or container determines bounds/size for the blocks.  Working with the content alignment can be done at either level or overridden by a specific "block".
I find the key to decent CSS is to remove as much as you can to get your desired result